# MariaDB - is it possible to index JSON arrays?

Tags: json, mariadb

When working with JSON in MariaDB it is possible to index single-point values using virtual columns e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE features ADD feature_street VARCHAR(30) AS (JSON_UNQUOTE(feature->"$.properties.STREET"));
ALTER TABLE features ADD INDEX (feature_street);
```

Does anybody know whether it is possible to index JSON arrays in the same way so that when querying based on the values of the array members, each array does not have to be scanned?

I can't find anything in the docs which suggests this is possible.

Comment: Currently not feasible in MySQL, probably not feasible, at the moment, in MariaDB, see [Indexing JSON documents via Virtual Columns by MySQL Server Blog](http://mysqlserverteam.com/indexing-json-documents-via-virtual-columns/#comment-13274).

Comment: @wchiquito great spot in the comments, thanks

Comment: It is now feasible in MySQL 8 to index JSON arrays. No idea if this feature is planned for MariaDB.

Comment: You sure about that, @Jim?

Comment: @Oddman - Yes, I've used it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued ; However, MariaDB devs do not appear to be in any hurry to add such indexes: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25848

Comment: @Jim damn, that's pretty cool. Hopefully they bring indexes to JSON objects soon!!! It's the one thing holding MySQL back in the modern database era...

Comment: @Oddman - Not sure if you mean indexing an entire object, but you can already index any scalar or array of scalars within a JSON object. It shows how in the same link I provided.

Comment: @Jim Yeah I mean a JSON object, not an array.

Comment: @Oddman, no, you can't index an entire JSON object. I don't believe any database does that as it would be rather complex. PostgreSQL gets close and can index all of an object's properties, but doesn't go deeper than the top level. It's also not quite as efficient as the indexes places on individual values.

Comment: @Jim multiple databases do it - including PostgresSQL. So does Google Firestore, MongoDB, list goes on ;) 

You're right in that Postgres doesn't go more than one level down, and that's fine - it's still a 1000x better than MySQL, which has no support at all.

Answer (score 3):

Create a "virtual" column of the element of the JSON column and index it.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/virtual-computed-columns/

The elements of an array inside a JSON string -- That is another matter.